# How do I get Redux state before the component re-renders?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Due to [how data flows](https://redux.js.org/basics/data-flow) through React-Redux apps, data that is updated in the store is not available in a React component until that component re-renders.

My ask is, within a given component I'd like to use the updated store *without* re-rendering the component. I am looking to do something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import * as AActions from "../aactions";
import * as BActions from "../bactions";
import * as CActions from "../cactions";
class MyComponent extends Component<Props>{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.func = this.func.bind(this);
    };

    func(){
        // Add item to A
        this.props.addAItem("value");

        // Get id of newly added item in A
        let addedA = this.props.A.find(a => a.name === "value");

        // Insert new items in B with the id of A
        this.props.addBItem(addedA.id, "valueB");

        // etc...
    }

    render(){
        <div onClick={() => this.func()}>click me</div>
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, props){
    return {
        A: state.A,
        B: state.B,
        C: state.C
    };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({...AActions, ...BActions, ...CActions}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

This **doesn't** work, because `props` is not updated until MyComponent re-renders. I cannot call `this.props.A.find(a => a.name === "value");` because props will not have the most recently-added "A" value. In my case, I can't wait for MyComponent to re-render. What are my options to access the most-recent state in MyComponent?

I've done something like this but it's absolutely horrible but it works...

```
func(){
    if (this.props.step1){
        // Add item to A
        this.props.addAItem("value");

        this.props.setStep2();
    } else if (this.props.step2) {
        // Get id of newly added item in A
        let addedA = this.props.A.find(a => a.name === "value");

        this.props.setStep3();
    }
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. - When the redux store updates, the props of your component will change, and a rerender will occur (assuming you haven't implmented a shouldCompoentUpdate method). Why would you want components internal state to to change without a rerender anyway?

Comment: @dwjohnston The reason behind this mode of thought is all of the actions are supposed to happen as a single unit, I cannot have MyComponent re-render, as doing so would require me to click that <div> again. I require multiple changes to the state (pulling out ids of most-recently inserted elements).

Comment: A component rerender won't reset the component state. Just set the component state on the onclick, and then dispatch?

Comment: @dwjohnston my component relies on the value from the store. The store's value (mapped as props) do not update until the component receives new props (and the component is re-rendered). 

Everything would work fine except my function requires user input, so after I call my first dispatch, the component re-renders and my func() doesn't continue executing, does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do to a *lot* of back and forth, and testing, I ran into many walls trying to figure this one out but eventually figured it out. Here's what you need to do.

> Note: This is not considered part of the React Redux public API, and may break without notice. We do recognize that the community has use cases where this is necessary, and will try to make it possible for users to build additional functionality on top of React Redux, but our specific use of context is considered an implementation detail. If you have additional use cases that are not sufficiently covered by the current APIs, please file an issue to discuss possible API improvements. - https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store#using-reactreduxcontext-directly

Ensure your **react** package is `16.8.3` or later. Ensure your **react-redux** package is `7.1` or greater. You need these versions because of the new way (in React 16.8.3) React passes down Context to child components. We care about Context because this new React Context API is how the **ReactReduxContext** works.

The [**ReactReduxContext**](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store#using-reactreduxcontext-directly) is the magic sauce we need in order to get the current state of the store in a component. Note the **changes** in our below component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { connect, ReactReduxContext } from "react-redux"; // CHANGED!

import * as AActions from "../aactions";
import * as BActions from "../bactions";
import * as CActions from "../cactions";
class MyComponent extends Component<Props>{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.func = this.func.bind(this);
    };

    func(store){ // CHANGED!
        // Add item to A
        this.props.addAItem("value");

        // Get id of newly added item in A
        let addedA = store.getState().A.find(a => a.name === "value"); // CHANGED!

        // Insert new items in B with the id of A
        this.props.addBItem(addedA.id, "valueB");

        // etc...
    }

    // CHANGED!
    render(){
        <ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
            {({store}) => {
                return <div onClick={() => this.func(store)}>click me</div>
            }}
        </ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, props){
    return {
        A: state.A,
        B: state.B,
        C: state.C
    };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({...AActions, ...BActions, ...CActions}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

The magic is `store.getState()` which returns the updated Redux store.

I want to point out I looked extensively at [`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk), but this approach didn't end up giving what I needed. The main problem is the use of **bindActionCreators** in my component. Because I am using **bindActionCreators**, any action that I call expects an empty object, which gets dispatched to the Redux store.

I attempted many ways to try and return the updated Redux state in an action but since I was using bindActionCreators, I could not return the value of the Redux state from a given action. The only way to retrieve an updated Redux store state *without* relying on the component itself to be updated/re-rendered is to use the method I outline above.

Answer (score 1):

Ok if I understand your question correctly, your func method addItemA then addItemB is dependant on the response from addItemA, addItemA would be an async operation, So in your addItemA action when you add the item you can simply return promise from your action which when resolves returns the id of newly created element and inside your component you can handle in a then block as

```
func(){
    // Add item to A
    this.props.addAItem("value").then((id) => {
    // no need to find the id now
    // Insert new items in B with the id of A
    this.props.addBItem(id, "valueB");

    });


     // etc...
  }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes I think this should do the trick, thank you for your answer!

Comment: If the answer helped please consider accepting and up voting, cheers :)

Comment: it has gotten me further, but now I am seeing "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions". Once I figure out more details I'd like to put that alongside this question and accept it.

Comment: I think you are returning function from action creator, you can use redux-thunk to resolve this issue, because by default actions are plain JS objects, redux-thunk allows you to return function from action creators, hope it clarifies

Comment: Thank you @ibtsam. I ended up taking a different approach that is working, please see my answer for more clarification. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

[shouldComponentUpdate](https://medium.com/voobans-tech-stories/5-ways-to-stop-wasting-renders-in-react-redux-73b3c5d86f50) should do the trick